# Matlab pcode: how to build a pcode version of my script keeping folder structure?

Tags: matlab

My Matlab script is organized as follows:

```
/main.m
/folder1/1a.m
/folder1/1b.m
/folder1/1c.m
/folder2/2a.m
/folder2/2b.m
/folder2/2c.m
...etc
```

Is there a way of running `pcode` so that I'd get, in a new separate folder, something like this:

```
/main.p
/folder1/1a.p
/folder1/1b.p
/folder1/1c.p
/folder2/2a.p
/folder2/2b.p
/folder2/2c.p
...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the '-inplace' option, that will place the p-file in the same directory as the m-file resides in.

So e.g.

```
pcode myFunction.m -inplace;
```

or in function syntax

```
pcode('myFunction.m', '-inplace');
```

should do the trick.
This is also well documented:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html

Comment: I tried this before posting the question: it only converts `main.m` to a pcode file. All others, inside folders, are untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will require the following steps:

1. Copy the folders that you want to `pcode`, can be done with `copyfile`
2. `pcode` the multiple files with the  `-inplace` flag as shown in the documentation
3. Remove all .m files from the new folder, can be done with `delete`